# Javascript: "private" variables when using modules

Tags: javascript

I am exporting a class where I do not want the user to be able to access the 
`name` variable. Is there anything wrong with doing it this way from a technical stand point, not personal preference?  I know it's probably not a best practice, but it seems to work.

```
let _name = 'bob';
export default class Person {
  getName() {
    return _name;
  }

  setName(name) {
    _name = name;
  }
}
```

Comment: You've basically implemented a singleton.

Comment: Try what happens with two instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simple - `_name` resides in a closure, and all instances of Person will set and get the same _name.

```
var a = new Person();
a.setName('John');

var b = new Person();
b.getName(); // the result will be John
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as what I see, my opinion is that `_name` is no longer private as per the code you've provided, because you are defining a `getter` and a `setter` method, which basically turns the variable to public.

You should also definitely take a look at @OriDrori's answer since he is right about the variable scope.